# Problem in creating adHoc build

Tags: iphone

"The app "App Name" was not installed on iphone "iphone name" because it is not signed."

I m getting this error when I try to create an adhoc build. I founds some solutions and tried those but none of them are working for me.
I have created a distribution certificate again and .mobileprovison certificates for 'n' numebr of times, but still i m getting this error. I have added Entitlements.plsit and also creating build for distribution configuration(which is copy of release). In organizer also it shows a valid provision profile. I m cleaning up Targets all the time when I create the build.
Am I missing any steps to create adhoc build. Please some one help me out of this. I m working on this issue from so many days.

Comment: Check if you are not accidentally creating a simulator build.

Comment: Yes, I was creating an simulator build. I tried with device build and its giving me an error - "The app "App Name" was not installed on iphone "iphone name" because the signer is not valid."

Comment: Then it is a problem of your certificate or profile. Try deleting and reinstalling your profile and certificate.Also check whether you are changing code signing settings for distribution configuration/scheme, for both project and target.

Comment: I have done both the things, deleting of certificates and creating new ones & also I m changing code signing settings for distribution in both, but still it giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps missing in your description of your problem, so it's unclear whether the problems are with the signing and packing of the ipa files or whether it's related to your installation of the app.

The good folks over at [TestFlightApp](http://www.testflightapp.com/) have provided an excellent step-by-step guide for [Xcode 3](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3) and [Xcode 4](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) on how this should be done.

It's not entirely black magic to make it work, but it's close. Just make sure you follow the steps one by one exactly as they are described and it should work - at least it did for me.

Comment: I m using xcode 3.2.5, when I create Entitelments.plist there is no key "get-task-allow". should i manually enter it into plist.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Entitlements.plist need full path.

Looks like

> ~/iOSProject/myProject/Entitlements.plist

I hope so that is a little problem for quick solution.